# Graphql query returning 10 digit number instead of query data

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have this landing page that is generated using a page query in gatsby-node.js that ideally will list all products contained in category x. With the page query I am passing the category name in Context.

```
    createPage({
        path: `/landings/${pathName}`,
        component: path.resolve(`src/templates/product-pages/landing.js`),
        context: {
            data: cat.name,
        },
```

In the Landing Function I am passing the category name into another function called Products that contains a query that lists all child products of the parent category and passes them back to Landing.

```
const Landing = (data) => {
    const title = data;
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{title.pageContext.data}</h1>
            <Products category={"product category"}/>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Landing;
```

```
const Products = ({category}) => {   
    console.log(query);
    return (
        <div>            
        </div>
    )
}

export const query = graphql`
query {
    allTaxonomyTermProductCategories(filter: {name: {in: "Backlit Film"}}) {
      nodes {
        relationships {
          commerce_product_variation__acyrlic {
            sku
          }
          commerce_product_variation__vinyl {
            sku
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default Products;
```

For an example I am passing "Backlit Film" but want it to pass in the category name it is getting from Landing. First problem I am having is the Products function returning a 10 digit hash code 2403848351, I know this is something to do with calling the query directly but not sure how else to fix it.

Comment: query is for [gatsby] internal usage, it doesn't exist on FC [at runtime ... page query can be used only on page component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach won't work that way. You are trying to create a [page query](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/) that, as the name points, only works in top-level components (pages), in your case, `Landing` component, not  `Products`.

What you have to do is to move the GraphQL query up to `Landing` component, get the result, and drill down the products to `Products`. Something like:

```
const Landing = ({data}) => {   
        return <div>
            <h1>{title.pageContext.data}</h1>
            <Products products={data.allTaxonomyTermProductCategories.nodes}/>
        </div>
}

export const query = graphql`
query {
    allTaxonomyTermProductCategories(filter: {name: {in: "Backlit Film"}}) {
      nodes {
        relationships {
          commerce_product_variation__acyrlic {
            sku
          }
          commerce_product_variation__vinyl {
            sku
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default Landing;
```

Alternatively, you can use a [`useStaticQuery` hook](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/use-static-query/), which will allow you to use queries in low-level components (`Products` in this case), the problem is that doesn't accept dynamic parameters (hence the *static* name)

---

Regarding the "10 digits". You are printing `query`, with is just an instance of the query. not the data that contains. Your data, will be stored inside `props.data`, that's why in my approach I'm destructuring the `props` as `data` (`{data}`).

Comment: thank you so much Ferran now I understand page queries cannot be used directly like I was and have to be passed down, gatsby guru